# Validating groups of checkboxes and radio buttons using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following groups of check-boxes and radio groups and was wondering how I would validate them each separately in VBA. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

For example I would require that at least checkbox is selected in the **weeks** group and each of the radio button groups (**priority**, **lecturestyle**, **roomstruc** and **roomtype**) just require a selection to be made. I would appreciate any code to show me how to accomplish this.

**weeks** - checkboxes

> chk_week1, chk_week2, chk_week3, chk_week4, chk_week5,..., chk_week15

**priority** - radio buttons

> priority_y, priority_n

**lecturestyle** - radio buttons

> lecturestyle_trad, lecturestyle_sem

**roomstruc** - radio buttons

> roomstruc_tiered, roomstruc_flat

**roomtype** - radio buttons

> roomtype_lecture, roomtype_lab

Comment: Check out Andy Pope's example here http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=49024. It assumes that you have used the groupname property for the controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. Naming a frame priority could return weird results so I have renamed your frames `frPriority` and `frLectureStyle`

```
Sub cbValidate_Click()
Dim ctl As Control, strOption As String, lLoop As Long

For lLoop = 1 To 15
    If Me.Controls("chk_week" & lLoop).Value = True Then GoTo nxtCheck0
Next

MsgBox "You didn't select a week"

nxtCheck0:

For Each ctl In Me.frPriority.Controls
    If ctl.Value = True Then GoTo nxtCheck1
Next

MsgBox "You didn't select a priority"

nxtCheck1:

For Each ctl In Me.frLectureStyle.Controls
    If ctl.Value = True Then GoTo nxtCheck1
Next

MsgBox "You didn't select a lecture Style"

nxtCheck1:

Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: `Exit For` may be nicer than using Goto

Comment: true, but where do I put my msgbox then? Put a boolean to catch the valid status and then use that?

Comment: I get the `Method or data member not found error` whenever I try and try to run the code. I think it has something to do with `Me.Priority.Controls`

Comment: The controls are on a user form

Comment: Can you rename your priority frame something different, something like frPriority

Comment: @nutch, I'd put the checks in functions at least, or in a class, at most, to avoid the GoTos.

Comment: Ok I will rename the priority frame

Comment: @nutsch unfortunately its still returning an error. Here are my settings so far for the priority radio buttons - http://i50.tinypic.com/b51f1g.png - is there anything I need to change. Its within a Frame called Frame1 along with the **priority**, **lecturestyle**, **roomstruc**, **roomtype** radio buttons.

Comment: You need one frame per group: one for priority, one for lecturestyle, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like the below coding as it gets tedious when you have many controls in group:

1. Insert a userform named “MyForm with checkboxes named “chk01”, “chk02”….”chk20 or however many checkboxes you want
2. Put the following declaration in a code module (not the form module)

   ```
   Public CheckBoxGroup(1 To 20) As New MyForm
   ```
3. Put the following declarations in the form code

   ```
   Public WithEvents ChkBoxGrp As CheckBox
   ```
4. Initialize the array in the form activate event

   ```
   Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
   Dim i As Integer
       For i = 1 To 20 (or however many checkboxes you have
               set CheckBoxGroup (i).ChkBoxGrp = MyForm("chk" + Right("0" + CStr(i), 2))
       Next i
   End Sub

   Private Sub ChkBoxGrp_Click()
       Select Case val(Right(ChkBoxGrp.Name, 2))
               Case 1
               ‘Do whaever you want for chk01 box
           Case 2
               ‘Do whaever you want for chk01 box
           ……………
           End Select
   End Sub
   ```

You can use the same event handling for other checkbox events